How to locally add SDL2 headers and lib to a project?
I want to learn more about local project management in C++ (clang++).
So I decided to wrote a simple C++ game without installing the libSDL2-devel package
Here is the structure of my project :
C++_Game/
--make.sh #my bash script to build the project
--sources
----main.cpp
--headers
----SDL2
---------SDL.h etc
--lib
----SDL2
---------libSDL2.a
---------libSDL2main.a
--obj
--bin
Here is my make.sh script :
CC="clang++ -std=c++14"
HEADERS="-I ./headers/"
LIBS="-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -L ./lib/SDL2/"
OBJ="./obj/*.o"
BIN="./bin/exec.out"

echo ">> COMPILE SOURCES"

$CC $HEADERS -c ./sources/main.cpp -o ./obj/main.o

echo ">> LINKING OBJECT FILES"

$CC $LIBS $OBJ -o $BIN

echo ">> RUN BIN"

$BIN

And here is the basic C++ code :
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
        std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

When I try to compile I get :
>> COMPILE SOURCES
>> LINKING OBJECT FILES
/usr/bin/ld: ./obj/main.o : dans la fonction « main » :
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
clang-15.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>> RUN BIN


Any idea of how to fix this error ?
Reading SDL2 doc
Asking on Google

Since you haven't installed libSDL2-devel package, are we to assume that you got your own version of it essentially in your projects and lib dirs?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Force make to emit the command lines and all shall, well maybe only should, will become clear.

Well, I extracted include and lib folder from this archive : https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/download/release-2.30.3/SDL2-devel-2.30.3-mingw.zip

One potential source of problems: $LIBS $OBJ <- the order is wrong. $LIBS does not depend on $OBJ. It's the other way around so make it $CC $OBJ $LIBS -o $BIN.

Not totally sure about this, but, for good measure, put the -L./lib/SDL2/ to the left of -lSDL2

You shouldn't change your code after receiving an answer. If the answer didn't work, post a comment under it saying so, instead of just silently changing the question.

You never specified what objects the linker should be linking in your link step, you only included the HEADERS and the LIBS but not your obj.
Strongly suggest you scrap your make.sh script and learn how to use make or CMAKE
that aside you also never use your $OBJ variable

I've corrected my makefile (see in my first post). But the linker is now throwing many errors. I think it's just due to the fact that I've used libs from SDL2-devel-2.30.3-mingw. It's made for Windows and more precisely for the mingw compiler not for GNU Linux (OpenSuse in my case)
